# How can I execute a PHP function via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How do I execute a PHP function using ajax? I have multiple functions on my script page but I want to call a single function.

```
<?php
    function one(){return 1;}
    function two(){return 2;}
?>
```

```js
$("#form").on('submit',(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}));
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What you want to do you want to send data through `AJAX` and get the `PHP` response or something else ?

Comment: pass an additional parameter in your ajax post which you can then check on the php page using isset and then run the specific function that you want to execute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a specific function from PHP with Jquery & Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677368/calling-a-specific-function-from-php-with-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Get param "action"

```js
$("#form").on('submit', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: "process.php?action=one",
    type: "POST",
    data: new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  });
}));
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Then in your process.php file, just catch the "action"

```
function one(){
 return 1;
}
function two(){
 return 2;
}


if ( isset($_GET['key']) && !empty(isset($_GET['key'])) ) {
  $action = $_GET['key'];
  
  switch( $action ) {
    case "one":{
       return 1; // or call here one();
    }break;

    case "two":{
       return 2; // or call here two();
    }break;

    default: {
      // do not forget to return default data, if you need it...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to do this without passing any parameter.

Comment: I undrstand, then you can add hidden input like `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="one" />` and catch again in your **process.php** the "action", this time via **POST**. It really depends on what you are trying to do with this form, because you have 1 form, but 2 functions and I don't get your idea in general ...

Answer (score 1):

You can call a specific function of your PHP code via AJAX by following few changes in your AJAX call and PHP code.

Eg:
**AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "yourphpfile.php",
    data: "function=one", // or function=two if you want the other to be called
   /* other params as needed */
});
```

Then in **yourphpfile.php** code,

```
<?php

function one(){return 1;}
function two(){return 2;}

    if(isset($_GET['function'])) {
        if($_GET['function'] == 'one') {
            function one() // call function one
        } elseif($_GET['function'] == 'two') {
            //function two() // call function two
        }
    }
?>
```